# sp_send_dbmail fails with EXECUTE but succeeds with SELECT

Tags: sql-server, database-administration, sp-send-dbmail

I have used this bit of code for years on SQL Server 2017 and it has always ran fine.

```
EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
@recipients = 'mymail@myaddress',
@subject = 'DailySecurityCheck',
@query = 'EXECUTE [database].[dbo].[pr_DailySecurityCheck]'
```

I just migrated to SQL Server 2019 and this now throws this error:

> Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259

I can run the `EXECUTE` statement successfully from SSMS.

I can replace the `@query` variable with a `SELECT` statement and it will run successfully.

I have also tried adding `@query_result_header = 1` and `@query_no_truncate = 0` with no luck.

I am not sure where to go from here.

Comment: What does the procedure do? Please show code.

Comment: It's  permissions related: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5552/troubleshooting-sql-server-spsenddbmail-error-failed-to-initialize-sqlcmd-library/

Comment: `-2147467259 == 0x80004005 == E_FAIL` == "[Unspecified failure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/705fb797-2175-4a90-b5a3-3918024b10b8#:~:text=Operation%20aborted.-,0x80004005,-E_FAIL)" == _fun..._

Answer (score 0):

Mitch, I looked at permissions and everything looked correct.
I have not "solved" the issue but I have found a work around. The last step that [database].[dbo].[pr_DailySecurityCheck] performed was to query a results table. I simply moved that query block from the procedure to the @query variable in sp_send_dbmail. Works perfect now.

Thanks everyone for offering suggestions.